# Как преобразовать десятичное число в шестнадцатеричную строку?

Tags: delphi

Есть число 98765432101234, как его преобразовать в бинарный формат 59 D3 9E 7F 19 72 ?

Comment: Уточните, что такое бинарный формат в вашем понимании? Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: кому тут что не понятно? из заголовка и тела вопроса вполне понятно все, разве нет?

Comment: @teran если интересно, то посмотрите первоначальную редакцию вопроса, по ней было неясно, что именно хотел ТС.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для новых делфи

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  num: Int64;
  str: string;
begin
  num := 98765432101234;
  str := IntToHex(num);
  ShowMessage(str);
end;
```

для старых

```
str := IntToHex(num, 0);
```

Если у вас всегда 6 байт и вы хотите видеть ведущие нули, то так

```
str := IntToHex(num, 12);
```

Comment: Маловероятно, что ему нужна *строка*.

Comment: @zed тогда ему вообще не нужно делать никаких преобразований

Comment: Ребят, все верно, мне нужна строка)

Comment: `format('%x', [num])` предложу в копилку

Comment: спрошу здесь же. как GUID размером 38 символов {01F903D6-47CD-4131-B28F-9BCAF2B27134}  преобразовать опять в бинарный вид (так написано в документации) как последовательность фиксированной длины (16 байт)? Не понимаю как 38 символов могут быть преобразованы в 16 байт. Или нужно создавать отдельную тему?

Comment: @SergeyB, из 38 символов две фигурные скобки и четыре дефиса. Остальные 32 символа - это шестнадцатеричная запись 16 байт

Comment: @SergeyB  если версии делфей не шибко древние то `StringToGuid():TGUID`